# Need to find errors in this shellscript to register a user for database

Tags: mysql, shell, debian

First of all I would like to say a big hello here as a freshly registered user!
OK, as the title already says, I need to find the errors in this shellscript for debian that is supposed to register new users to a mysql database. The code in this script may be interesting for others, too, so everybody reading this thread may benefit from the solution in the end. The comments are in Spanish, so I hope this won't be too inconvinient. But if required, I can provide a translation of the comments later.

```html
#!/bin/bash
# Este script crea una base de datos, y un usuario con permisos para operar en ella.
# Defaults
DB_ROOT=""
DB_ROOT_PASS=""
DB_NAME=""
DB_USER=""
DB_PASS=""
 
# Recogemos el input del usuario
read -e -p " + Usuario root del servidor mysql: " DB_ROOT
read -e -s -p " + Contraseña root para el servidor mysql: " DB_ROOT_PASS; echo
read -e -p " + Nombre de la base de datos (sin espacios ni caracteres especiales): " DB_NAME
read -e -p " + Nombre del nuevo usuario mysql (o uno ya existente): " DB_USER
read -e -s -p " + Contraseña del nuevo usuario: " DB_PASS;
echo 
echo
# Creamos el nuevo usuario sql
mysql -u ${DB_ROOT} -p${DB_ROOT_PASS} -e "CREATE USER '${DB_USER}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${DB_PASS}'; GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO '${DB_USER}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${DB_PASS}';"
 
# Comprobamos errores
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        echo " El usuario ${DB_USER} se ha creado con éxito."
 
        # Creamos la nueva base de datos
        mysql -u ${DB_ROOT} -p${DB_ROOT_PASS} -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${DB_NAME} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${DB_NAME} . * TO '${DB_USER}'@'localhost';"
 
        # Comprobamos errores
        if [ $? == 0 ]; then
                echo " La base de datos ${DB_NAME} se ha creado con éxito."
                echo " El usuario ${DB_USER} tiene permisos sobre la base de datos ${DB_NAME}."
        else
                mysql -u ${DB_ROOT} -p${DB_ROOT_PASS} -e "DROP USER '${DB_USER}'@'localhost';"
                exit
        fi
 
else
        echo " Si mysql devuelve ERROR 1396 probablemente signifique que el usuario que intentas crear ya existe."
        echo " Prueba otro nombre de usuario."
        exit
fi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the site does not let me post the code, it says that it is not properly formatted as code. Well it seems that this is partly thge problem of the code, so what D I do? Can I attach it as a file?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use the syntax highlighter feature of the text editor to format the code properly. Here you can learn how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: OK, just found out that I could post it as "html snippet" which is what I am used to from other forums.

Comment: Has nobody seen the code yet or is there nobody that can help me in the end?